# System.UnauthorizedAccessException loading file from Disk

Tags: asp.net, filestream, server.mappath

Really weird problem loading a file from disk:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Datasets/blob.xml");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```

Throws exception:

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path 'D:\webroot\afob\Dev\v1.0.x\AFOB\Datasets\blob.xml' is denied.

The strange thing is it was working 5 minutes ago.  I checked permissions on the disk and both the Debugger and ASPNET have read/write rights as do I.

Ideas?

Comment: What user is the ApplicationPool running as? Does that user have access to the folder?

Comment: Logged off and rebooted, same issue.

Comment: What user is the ApplicationPool running as? http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/ Does that user have access to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Did you dispose the stream the last time you opened it:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Datasets/blob.xml");
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    ...
}
```

But in this case I suspect it's really a permissions issue. You could [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from SysInternals to see exactly what process is trying to open the file and under which account this process executes.

Comment: I close the stream every time.  I will try Procmon, any other ideas?  Why would it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Problem solved!  Turns out everytime I did a check-in, TFS wouldnt allow me to read the file, so I just checked it out.  THanks for your suggestions.