# Why can't I read XML from AppData in WinRT?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

**What I want**
get a xml file from the AppData.Local, and serialize it to a list

**What I code**
The Error Part:

```
List<myTask> AllTaskList = await  objectStorageHelper.LoadAsync();
```

myTask is a simple class:

```
public class myTask
{
    public string myTitle { get; set; }
    public string myDuetime { get; set; }
}
```

objectStorageHelper is a HelpClass from [CodePlex](http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/), the LoadAsync part is below:

```
    public async Task<T> LoadAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = null;
            StorageFolder folder = GetFolder(storageType);
            file = await folder.GetFileAsync(FileName());
            //file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("BetterTask.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            Stream inStream = Task.Run(() => readStream.AsStreamForRead()).Result;
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(inStream);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //file not existing is perfectly valid so simply return the default 
            return default(T);
            //Interesting thread here: How to detect if a file exists (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1eb71a80-c59c-4146-aeb6-fefd69f4b4bb)
            //throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Unable to load contents of file
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**What is the Error**

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access Denied。 (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

**--**
Why does this happen？
I can use this help class to successfully write to a file.
But Why don't I have the permission to read the file?
How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5330436/1207991

Comment: does your application has authorization to read this file/directory ?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
StorageFolder folder = GetFolder(storageType);
```

to

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

if this works then the issue is with your folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 Stream inStream = Task.Run(() => readStream.AsStreamForRead()).Result;
 return (T)serializer.Deserialize(inStream);
```

to

```
using (Stream inStream = Task.Run(() => readStream.AsStreamForRead()).Result)
{
    return (T)this.xmlSerializer.Deserialize(inStream);
}
```

or

```
inStream.Flush();
inStream.Dispose();
```

and the same to the SaveAsync()

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't really answer the question